# CXF: cannot logging soap messages

Tags: logging, soap, cxf, config

In a standard eclipse java project where is the correct location of cxf.xml config file? I'm trying to enable soap messages logging on a stand alone jar format client ws consumer. Produced artifacts with wsdltojava utility and using the autogenerated starting point test client it works really fine. 
I created config file as per documentation but in my consolle i don't see anything going on. 
this is the my cxf.xml file content:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
      xsi:schemaLocation=" 
http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

<bean id="abstractLoggingInterceptor" abstract="true">
    <property name="prettyLogging" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="loggingInInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor"/>
<bean id="loggingOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor"/>

<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
    <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
    <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
</cxf:bus>  

</beans>
```

I tried to put it in project root and under src but nothing. What I'm missing?

My client code is like:

public final class ClientMHttps {

```
private static final QName SERVICE_NAME = new       QName("http://thecompany/service-b", "myendpoint-v1");

private  myendpointPortType port ;

public ClientMHttps() throws java.lang.Exception {
    URL wsdlURL = myendpointV1.WSDL_LOCATION;

    myendpointV1 ss = new myendpointV1(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
    port = ss.getmyendpointPortTypeEndpointHttpsM(); 




}

    public DeleteMarkedStatusResponse do_DeleteMarkedStatus(DeleteMarkedStatusRequest  _deleteMarkedStatus_body) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    System.out.println("Invoking deleteMarkedStatus...");
    javax.xml.ws.Holder<HeaderType> _header =  this.HeaderFarm();
    DeleteMarkedStatusResponse _deleteMarkedStatus__return = port.deleteMarkedStatus(_deleteMarkedStatus_body, _header);
    System.out.println("deleteMarkedStatus.result=" + _deleteMarkedStatus__return);
    return _deleteMarkedStatus__return;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe is just the bean names and the cxf.xml location that needs to be fixed.

In src/main/resources/cxf.xml you can use a cxf.xml file like this to log all CXF messages:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="logInbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>
    <bean id="logOutbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logInbound"/>
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logOutbound"/>
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
        <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logOutbound"/>
        </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
        <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logInbound"/>
        </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
    </cxf:bus> 
</beans>
```

Comment: no way! I tried to move cxf.xml everyware but doesnt work! Keep in mind that i have created a stand alone client, not a servlet. So under src I just have my app packeges (it.bla.etc.).

Comment: I also have a stand alone client and it logs fine, did you try to move cxf.xml to src/main/resources/? You can just create the folders and place the file there then it should log.

Comment: I did it but nothing. Soap message loging is related to default log level? My logging level in logging properies is setted to FINE

Answer (score 0):

A `<jaxws:client>` element should be added to your Spring configuration file (cxf.xml) that will create a CXF Web Services client. You will then need to use this client bean in your code to invoke the web service.

Depending on the logging framework you want to use you might need to configure the `META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger` as described [here](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html#DebuggingandLogging-UsingLog4jInsteadofjava.util.logging).

I've created blog posts which explain how to configure CXF for [log4j](http://www.source4code.info/2015/01/jaxws-cxf-logging-request-response-soap-messages-log4j.html), [logback](http://www.source4code.info/2014/09/jaxws-cxf-logging-inbound-outbound-soap-messages-logback.html) or [log4j2](http://www.source4code.info/2015/01/jaxws-cxf-logging-request-response-soap-messages-log4j2.html) in more detail.

*Note that you could also use the CXF logging feature, which is less verbose.*

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a filter for 'org.apache.cxf.services'.

```
<logger level="INFO" name="org.apache.cxf.services"/>
```

Logging is not generated for the package of the implementing service class, but rather at a custom location.